# Please synonymize [built-in-types] and [primitive-types] into [primitive]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive) has existed for three years, with [primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitives) as a tag synonym.

According to the tag wiki and tag excerpt, the tag is for questions specific to primitive data types (or basic types / built-in data types). This makes it synonymous to [primitive-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive-types) and [built-in-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in-types).

`primitive-types` and `built-in-types` has *far* fewer questions and activity compared. `built-in-types` doesn't even have a proper tag wiki. Please synonymize them!

Comment: I disagree: a built-in type is not necessarily a primitive. For example in Java a `String` is a built-in type, but it is definitely not a primitive.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Several languages re-defines "primitive types". For example, Java separates "Object types" from "primitive types", but that does not change that primitive data types are _defined_ as basic types or built-in data types. In this case, `String` in Java is a basic type.

Comment: A string is definitely not a primitive, it is a composite data type, which just happens to have special first class support defined in the language specification. The same goes for `Class`, `Object`, etc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: It is implemented in standard library: `src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java` not by JDK, so if you delete `rt.jar`, it is probably gone (which breaks many other things, but who cares :) )