# Synonymise [primitive-types] into [primitive]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Related: [Please synonymize [built-in-types] and [primitive-types] into [primitive]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290664/1364007) (from 2015) which also mentions the [built-in-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in-types) tag - the comments on the other question question whether or not [built-in-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in-types) should be included.

- The [primitive-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive-types) tag has 773 questions and 10 watchers.

  Its excerpt says

  > Built-in types in any programming language that are defined in an axiomatic way and cannot be divided into other types in the language.
- The [primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive) has 931 questions and 16 watchers.

  Its excerpt says

  > A  primitive type is a data type provided by a programming language as a basic building block.

  and is clearly also talking about the concept of [primitive data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type).

There's clearly no point having two tags that refer to the same concept - one should be a synonym of the other - I propose that [primitive-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive-types) be made a synonym of [primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive).

I can't suggest a synonym (in either direction) directly because I don't have a score of 5 or more on either tag.

Answer (score 8):

The [primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive) tag has the same guidance but may not in practice be used the same way - a quick glance suggests most questions tagged [primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive) are about primitive data types, but there are a few where the tag is misused. I don't mean to single out these examples specifically, they're just the ones that were easiest to find by searching:

- [What is the concept of "third" in Primitive function scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897788/what-is-the-concept-of-third-in-primitive-function-scheme)
- [How to implement custom naming for multioutput primitives in FeatureTools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637245/how-to-implement-custom-naming-for-multioutput-primitives-in-featuretools)
- [Java syntax and logic help "?" and ":"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68726713/java-syntax-and-logic-help-and) - here "primitive" doesn't seem to have any specific meaning related to the question, maybe the asker thought that their question was primitive (i.e. basic)?

The two tags should clearly be synonymised, but I'd argue that [primitive-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive-types) is the one that should stay, because it's less likely to be misused like in these examples.

Regarding [built-in-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in-types), this is a separate concept because not all built-in types are primitive (e.g. `String` in Java). So it should stay as a separate tag, though no doubt there are many questions in that tag which would be better tagged as [primitive-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primitive-types) because a lot of askers won't be aware of the distinction.